# Adding a new object to an array through ngFor directive with angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

i'm traying to display n filds through ngFor directive(user imput) that correspand to a User instance  But my question is what is the best way to put this object values in this array after validation click buttom.

```
  <ul style="list-style-type: none">
  <li *ngFor="let number of nbCollaborateur">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Nom et prenom </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group form-black label-floating is-empty">
            <label class="control-label">telephone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group form-black label-floating is-empty">
            <label class="control-label">adresse</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group form-black label-floating is-empty">
            <label class="control-label">commantaire</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My array will look like this:

```
users: User[];
this.users.push(new User());
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question..

Comment: How to retrieve user fields in the component part from this sample template?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any button in your html. But you can handle validation logic in component and then push to array.

If you add a new item to array, it automatically will get added to the template as you have *ngFor loop.

Here are some useful links for your use case:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4&t=804s

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html